# Bad mpd audio playback with fifo enabled

Tags: macos, audio, mpd

I am using Music Player Daemon ([`mpd`](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon_Wiki)) with [`ncmpcpp`](http://ncmpcpp.rybczak.net) on OS X. `ncmpcpp` has a feature, the music visualizer, that draws a realtime wave/spectrum of the music you are currently playing.

In order to use this you have to enable the fifo output in `mpd`.

Well, it works but while this is on the audio is terrible: It crackles and sometimes even freezes. It’s like if `mpd` is skipping some frame.

The `mpd` settings for the fifo are:

```
audio_output {
  type   "fifo"
  name   "FIFO"
  path   "/tmp/mpd.fifo"
  format "44100:16:2"
}
```

And `ncmpcpp` has set:

```
visualizer_in_stereo = "yes"
visualizer_fifo_path = "/tmp/mpd.fifo"
visualizer_output_name = "fifo"
visualizer_sync_interval = "0"
visualizer_look = "||"
visualizer_color = "blue"
visualizer_type = "spectrum"
```

Is there some wrong setting to change or I have found a bug?

Comment: I can confirm this, audio begins stuttering if I enable FIFO output. ncmpcpp is not the cause of the problem, it also happens with mpdviz.

Comment: @shrx Are you also on OS X?

Comment: Yes, OS X 10.10.2, mpd 0.19.9 installed with homebrew.

Comment: I filed a bug [report](http://bugs.musicpd.org/view.php?id=4316).

Answer (score 2):

I filed a bug [report](http://bugs.musicpd.org/view.php?id=4316) on the mpd bug tracker.
The issue is related to the OS X audio output plugin which is unmaintained.
So the only way to keep both regular audio output and FIFO is to stream to another player.

You can output through http or another fifo and stream the audio to vlc for instance.
In the case of http add to your config:

```
audio_output {
  type "httpd"
  name "http stream"
  encoder "vorbis"
  port "8000"
  quality "2"
  format "44100:16:2"
}
```

then set this alias: `alias cvlc='/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC --intf=rc'`

and run `cvlc http://localhost:8000`

In case you want to use two FIFOs just duplicate the current settings and start vlc with:

```
cvlc --demux=rawaud --rawaud-channels 2 --rawaud-samplerate 44100 /tmp/mpd-vlc.fifo
```

The downsides I have noticed are that you won't be able to change output volume with mpd anymore and there is a relatively small lag.

Comment: I have the same problem but for some reason http streaming does not solve the problem -- music still interrupting - no matter if it's streaming through the http or just using CoreAudio and FIFO... The only way it works for me is having Visualizer open. If I change the tab with Tab key for example it starts interrupting until I press 8 to show the Visualizer back or until I disable FIFO visualizer leaving only CoreAudio (or http stream)… Weird…

Comment: @Andrew I had the exact same problem: if you close the visualizer the audio starts freezing. For me using the http output solved it. However I switched completely to linux so I can't work on this anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I notice you have
    visualizer_sync_interval = "0"
in your config, which is almost certainly the problem. First try setting it to "30", as is recommended in the ncmpcpp docs--if that doesn't work, try out several different values for that parameter.

Comment: I think the problem is with mpd, the problem persists even when ncmpcpp is not running.